# Do I have to “New Game” to speed-run Superliminal?

Tags: superliminal

I want to attempt Superliminal's speed run achievements (completing the game in 60 or 30 minutes). Do I have to choose the “New Game” menu option, which has the annoying side effect of resetting the level select and secret-finding progress, to qualify for the speed run?

Answer (score 2):

Starting your run with **Select Level → 1. Induction** will still qualify you for a speedrun achivement. It also counts for the onscreen speedrun timer, even though **Options → Gameplay Settings → Speedrun Timer** says “Note: only available through new game”.

Additional characteristics:

- If you save and quit, this will disqualify the run.
- Resetting to checkpoint from the pause menu will not disqualify but will not rewind the timer.
- The pause menu pauses the timer.